# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Truck' to data type bit

Tags: sql, sql-server

When i am trying to run the below query. It works really fine.

```
SELECT  DelayId, DelayCategory, DelayReason FROM
[TAMS].[DelayMaintenance] 
WHERE IsUtilized = 1
AND Truck = 1
union      SELECT 0, NULL, '--- Pick One----'
ORDER BY DelayId
```

[image]

But when I am trying to use same query but parameters in where. It gives me an error.

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Truck' to data type bit.

DECLARE @CheckPointType VARCHAR(50) = 'Truck'
DECLARE @BitConveyance BIT = 1

SELECT  DelayId, DelayCategory, DelayReason FROM
[TAMS].[DelayMaintenance] 
WHERE IsUtilized = 1
AND @CheckPointType = @BitConveyance -- Issue is here
union      SELECT 0, NULL, '--- Pick One----'
ORDER BY DelayId
```

Comment: well, of course, you are doing this: `@CheckPointType = @BitConveyance`, but those variables have different data types. Seems that you want to use dynamic SQL, but you need to actually do it the "dynamic" part of it

Comment: @Lamak. please suggest how can i rewrite this to get my result

Comment: You can't use a variable for a column name.

Comment: you could search for dynamic SQL. I'm on mobile so I don't fancy writing an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Lamak hinted, you need to use dynamic SQL. Something like this might work

```
DECLARE @CheckPointType VARCHAR(50) = 'Truck'
DECLARE @BitConveyance BIT = 1
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT  DelayId, DelayCategory, DelayReason FROM [TAMS].[DelayMaintenance] WHERE IsUtilized = 1 AND ' + @CheckPointType + ' = ' + CAST(@BitConveyance AS CHAR(1)) + 
           ' union      SELECT 0, NULL, ''--- Pick One----'' ORDER BY DelayId'

EXEC (@SQL)
```